# Backbone fetch preventing JQuery prepended element to be displayed

Tags: jquery, html, backbone.js, prepend

I'm displaying a notification before synchronously loading some data with Backbone ; the notification is not shown. It is shown only when I put a breakpoint just after the notify call!

The code looks like that:

```
PM.notify($.i18n.prop('loading_project'));

PM.project = new PM.Project({id: id});
PM.project.fetch({async:false});
PM.projects[id] = PM.project;
;;; other async calls follows but are not included here to save space...

PM.notify = function(text) {
$('.notification-area').prepend('<ul class="thankyou pm-thankyou"><li class="notification">{0}</li></ul>'.format(text));
}
```

I tried setting the async to true and it causes the notification to be displayed however I don't want an async call to be performed in this case.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When you set the breakpoint after the notify(), the application stops there and there will be enough time to fetch the data and then call the notify(). It means that the breakpoint actually makes those code to be async.

I am very interesting that why you don't want the async call here. I think that's the point.

Comment: The notify function is called before fetching the data, so I don't understand why it isn't displayed. I need the project data before displaying the project page, so I though it would be simpler to make the call synchronous.

Comment: Usually this kind of things should be done on the server side. The web server should render the page template and then transfer this page to frontend. In the front side, we may use some loading gif to cover those parts that not rendered.

Comment: My templates are rendered on the frontend with the JS IcanHaz library.

Comment: I don't know how you define the 'displaying the project page'. I think that it's very difficult to fetch data from server not with async operation. You may load a blank page first, then start to fetch the data, after the data arrives, use it to generate the DOM you want and then insert into your page.